# Figure caption does not continue on new page

Tags: captions, page-breaking

I have a large figure caption that I want to display. However, it just runs off the page into nowhere instead of onto the next page. What command do I need to fix this? Googling the problem doesn't seem to help, but I probably just don't know what to type in.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Schematic.PNG}
  \caption{Really Long Caption Here\label{fig:apparatus} }
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Picture of caption running off the page.]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It won't naturally!. Why do you want such a big caption. Give small caption and add explanations in the text (main body).

Comment: It seems strange not to though, what if my figure started near the bottom of the page and ended where the last normal line was? Then I would have no room for a caption. I feel that I need the large caption because I have so many parts to describe on the apparatus. It would be weird to mention part a outside of the caption, I think.

Comment: That is why they float!

Comment: Okay, well thank you for your help. I'll reduce the size of the caption.

Comment: Welcome to the site! @HarishKumar an answer? too localized?

Comment: @cmhughes I will go for too localised!

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the large caption, this is an alternative. My study shows that if the floating feature is disabled, then the caption can continue to the next page, as shown below.   Here a new environment called `figurhere` is defined

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}
\makeatletter
```

Note: remove the `demo` option for actual case implementation.

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   <--- remove demo option for actual case
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}
\makeatletter



\begin{document}

\begin{figurehere}
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\tet]{Schematic.PNG}
  \caption{\blindtext
                \blindtext
                \blindtext
                \blindtext
                end of caption
\label{fig:apparatus}}
 \end{center}
\end{figurehere}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for creativity. Nevertheless, just in case anyone harbors any doubts: this is an answer of the "how something *could* be done" rather than the "how it *should* be done" variety. Captions of figures and tables work best if they're concise and introductory in nature. Multi-line explanatory material belongs either in the body of the float or (quite likely) in the body of the text, *not* in the float's caption.

Comment: @Mico -- Agree with your point totally and thank you for pointng that out. `This is something could be done`. Yes, caption should be short and concise.